# Online Torah Scroll

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, sefer-torah

Is there an online virtual Sefer Torah (in 3D) that could be rolled and unrolled?

Comment: Obviously it wouldn't have the sanctity of a real Torah scroll. Are you asking if anyone has put up some sort of animation? What would be the advantages?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. It would just be an interesting thing, that's all. They have VR versions of everything so I thought maybe someone might had made as you said, a nice animation of a Torah scroll.

Comment: Here is a complete open source online scan of a Torah scroll https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sefer-Torah-Elihu-Shannon-2.djvu

Comment: This post contains two questions: 1) Does this product exist, and 2) Would it be halachically problematic. These are two very different kinds of questions, and I think they should be addressed in separate posts. Therefore, I would encourage you to [edit] the second question out of this post, post it as a separate question post, and when you do so, clarify what kinds of halachic issues you think may apply (e.g. permissibility of creating such a product, suitability of such a product for use in a synagogue service, permissibility of casual use, conditions of use, etc.)

Comment: Did anyone ever find a VR Torah scroll?

Answer (score 2):

By definition a Torah scroll used in synagogue must be made of parchment. An online version would just be images, no different from any other online file.

From [Maimonides](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.1.8?ven=The_Mishneh_Torah_by_Maimonides._trans._by_Moses_Hyamson,_1937-1949&vhe=Torat_Emet_370&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en):

> It is a rule dating back to Moses who received it on Sinai that the scroll of the Law should be written on Gewil (whole hide parchment), and the writing should be on the side which had been next to the hair.

Comment: Aside from the point that it can't be used on Shabbos and Yom Tov(!)

Comment: Of course, but aren't there Chumashim with the Torah written not on parchment and websites with the complete text of the Torah? How is it different to give it a slightly different digital representation, as you have said (no different from any other online file.) And you are right there are those who would attempt to access such a thing on Shabbat and Yom Tov. Not pushing the idea to market, but B&H photo and ArtScroll both have ways of dealing with this (I know because I'm on a different continent and after Havdallah they are still enjoying Shabbat rest)

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question

Comment: @DoubleAA, this appears to be addressing the last part of the post, which may be better off as a separate post.

Comment: @IsaacMoses And what halachic problem exactly is there exactly? Or is this saying there isn't a problem?

Comment: @DoubleAA I closed the question and commented asking for severance and clarification of that point.

Comment: @DoubleAA This seems to answer the unedited version of the question, which could be read as asking about an online Sefer Torah for ritual use

Comment: @JoelK Correct. I just saw the new version of the question, which makes my answer irrelevant.